# Selecting everything from sql database with php and android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1uq36sbd6d7a3gr/Untitled.png?dl=0

I am connecting to my .php file through my android app which then connects to my sql database, it then grabs all the info I have saved there by receiving a username and getting all info with the same username and displays it in a recycler viewer. So far it's only showing me the last pet. How do I tell my code to show ALL the pets under that username.

**JAVA CODE**

```
**RECEIVE PET**
public class ReceivePet extends StringRequest {

private static final String RECEIVE_PET_URL = "http://lassie.netai.net/ReceivePet.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public ReceivePet (String username, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super(Request.Method.POST, RECEIVE_PET_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("username", username);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
```

}

```
**WHERE I GET MY SQL DATABASE INFO**
Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                if (success) {
                    petName = jsonResponse.getString("petname");
                    petBreed = jsonResponse.getString("petbreed");
                    phoneNumber = jsonResponse.getString("phonenumber");
                    petDescription = jsonResponse.getString("petdescription");
                    imageUrl = jsonResponse.getString("imageurl");

                    petsList.add(new Pet(petName, petBreed, phoneNumber, petDescription, imageUrl));
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    ReceivePet receiverPetRequest = new ReceivePet(username, responseListener);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    queue.add(receiverPetRequest);
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("mysql13.000webhost.com", "a9017958_omer", "pass123", "a9017958_users");

$username = $_POST["username"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM pets WHERE username = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $petsID, $username, $petname, $petbreed, $phonenumber, $petdescription, $imageurl);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)) {
    $response["success"] = true;
    $response["petname"] = $petname;
    $response["petbreed"] = $petbreed;
    $response["phonenumber"] = $phonenumber;
    $response["petdescription"] = $petdescription;
    $response["imageurl"] = $imageurl;
}

print_r (json_encode($response));
```

?>

Comment: first make sure on `ServerSide` you have All data you expect ? run `php` file in browser first

Comment: Of course I do, I'm receiving only one pet, instead of the two I have.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2klqgip09cow34p/sdjklnfodsf.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

In `PHP` in the `while` loop, you're overwriting the values in the `$response` at each iteration. You need to create an array of arrays. Here is an example:

```
$response = array();
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)) {
    $entry = array();
    $entry["success"] = true;
    $entry["petname"] = $petname;
    $entry["petbreed"] = $petbreed;
    $entry["phonenumber"] = $phonenumber;
    $entry["petdescription"] = $petdescription;
    $entry["imageurl"] = $imageurl;
    $response[] = $entry;
}
```

Also, you should use `echo json_encode($response);` instead of `print_r(json_encode($response));`.

And in Java, since now you're getting a JSON array as a response. You need to change:

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
```

to:

```
JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(response);
```

and loop through this array to process all the results.

```
for(int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length(); i++){
    JSONObject obj = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(i);
    petsList.add(new Pet(obj.getString("petname"), obj.getString("petbreed"),....));
}
```

Comment: This is great thank you! can you just show me the loop for looping through the result, would really appreciate it! :)

Comment: I'm getting an error now though on "success" says JsonArray cannot be applied to jav.lang.string

JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(response);
boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

Comment: @OmerValentine Remove that line `boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");`, is not needed anymore, if the process was unsuccessful, the `JSONArray` will be empty. You can do this instead `boolean success = jsonResponse.length() > 0;`.

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value {"success":false,"0":{"petname":"Lassie","petbreed":"Terrier","phonenumber":"050929252","petdescription":"Lassie is white, responds to calls by her name and her nickname Lass.","imageurl":"http:\/\/lassie.netai.net\/pictures\/Lassie-05-092-9252.JPG"},"1":{"petname":"Dj","petbreed":"Dj","phonenumber":"5147441527","petdescription":"sdjihfiusdahfiudhsfgiuhsdiufhgihsdiugfhiushdfg","imageurl":"http:\/\/lassie.netai.net\/pictures\/Dj-8653.JPG"}} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Now getting this error